# jQuery Mobile Custom download of collapsible set not working/triggering on load?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Hi I am new to jquery mobile so forgive me if this is a stupid question.

I'm trying to implement a collapsible set on my page. I have downloaded a custom file from the jquery mobile website using the download builder and just choosing the  collapsible set widget, which automatically selects what I assume are the necessary functions to include.

I've followed the instructions on the getting started guide, linked the css files and the custom js file which do load I've checked with firebug.

I've added the appropriate html markup but it fails to do anything when the page loads.

If I try using the entire Jquery mobile v.1.45 file then the collapsable set works but it starts  altering other elements on my page like form buttons among other things, messing with my design. As you can understand I don't want it doing that.

I've built my website using drupal I don't know if that matters.

Has anyone else experienced this, is this a bug, is there a work around, am I doing something drastically wrong?

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

My mark up is simply:

```html
<div class="ui-collapsible-set field-items" data-corners="false" data-content-theme="a" data-theme="a" data-role="collapsibleset">

  <div class="field-item even" data-role="collapsible">
    <h2>Heading:</h2>
    <p> my text </p>
  </div>

  <div class="field-item even" data-role="collapsible">
    <h2>Heading:</h2>
    <p> my text </p>
  </div>

  <div class="field-item even" data-role="collapsible">
    <h2>Heading:</h2>
    <p> my text </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since it's not a full version, then any widget won't be initialized automatically. Therefore, you need to initialize custom widgets manually.

```
$(function() {
  $("#collapssible-set-ID").collapsibleset();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for that, works a treat now :) (FYI tried to upvote your answer but apparently I don't have enough reputation points.)

Comment: Another quick question, any idea why the + and - icon doesn't show? It's just an empty circle next to the heading.